# How to make setTimeout in javascript work for a defined function?

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
  animatePress(userChosenColor);
})

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("." + currentColor).addClass("pressed");
}

setTimeout(animatePress,2000);
```

So when I press the button on my website, the "pressed" class is applied (to make it darker) but the setTimeout doesn't work to make it revert back to its original colour. I followed the layout for the functions carefully so I don't know why it's not working. Thanks in advance

Edit:
This is my jquery script in my HTML, could it be because of that?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: the setTimeout is NOT inside the click function. Also could be toogleClass instead addClass as the timeout will not remove the class effect

Comment: Why should it be inside?

Comment: Actually I just tried putting it inside the click function, and it still doesn't timeout

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example?

Comment: @argonx How do you want to put the timeout relative to when you clicked, if you don't start the timeout when the button is clicked? (Right now it will be scheduled as soon as the code is ran, which is presumably on page load.)

Comment: @argonx If you put it inside probably is calling setTimeout but you're adding "pressed" class twice. Try `toggleClass()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
    animatePress(userChosenColor);
    setTimeout(() => animatePress(userChosenColor),2000);
})

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("." + currentColor).toggleClass("pressed");
}
```

Comment: @Ivar  True.Edited the answer, sry

Comment: Ivar, do you mean that setTimeout does not work with change in colour?

Comment: @argonx I have edited 30s ago, did u try after i edited?

Comment: @Jon yes it workkss thank you! But I don't understand the "() =>" what does that mean?

Comment: @argonx https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @argonx It is called Anonymos function it would be equal to doing `setTimeout(function () { animatePress(userChosenColor),2000);}`

Comment: And as @Ivar has posted, the syntax is like an arrow function avalaible since ECMAScript 6

Answer (score 0):

You `setTimeout` is outside of the click which will not execute like that as its does not know where the `userChoosenColor` is:

Try this code should just work fine.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var userChosenColor = $(this).attr("id");
  setTimeout(function() {
    animatePress(userChosenColor)
  }, 2000);
})

function animatePress(currentColor) {
  $("." + currentColor).toggleClass("pressed");
  console.log('I am Called')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Now it has another effect, the "pressed" class is added after 2 seconds

Comment: @argonx is not that what you wanted to add `pressed` after two seconds ?

Comment: @argonx use `.toggleClass()` insread if you are changing the effect after two seconds. `.addClass` will just add and will not disappear after `pressed` class is added.

Comment: No I wanted to remove it after 2 seconds, I am sorry for not making that clear before but thank you for you help anyway, much appreciated, now someone else posted a solution so its ok, i still gave u an upvote though

Comment: @argonx No worries. Glad that i could help. The accepted answer is same as mine. I said the same thing to use `toggleClass()` instead. Glad that we helped you :)

Comment: @argonx Thanks Heaps. I appreciate it.